# Finding max/min values in each cell of Pandas in Python

Tags: python, pandas

I am new to Pandas, I have a csv data file and I am trying to find max and min values for each row for a particular column. That data looks something like this:

```py
0          PK,K,1,2,3,4,5
1    PK,K,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8
2    PK,K,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8
3                   K,1,2
4                PK,K,1,2
```

This is 1 of the columns of my CSV file (first 5 rows out of ~600 rows). As you can see it has multiple values in each cell (Those are grades offered by a school). How can I find a min and max values from this information? Thanks in advance

I tried using dataFrame.max()/ dataFrame.min(), but that gives a max/min value for the whole row or column. My problem is more specific to a cell. Also I have thought of converting each cell into a list and then I can find max/min using python default functions, but I really don't want to do it that way. I want to stick to Pandas and dataframes

```py
length_ = gradesOffered.shape
print(length_)
print(gradesOffered.iloc[0:5,0])
print(gradesOffered.iloc[0:5,0].max())

Output:
(660, 1)
0          PK,K,1,2,3,4,5
1    PK,K,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8
2    PK,K,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8
3                   K,1,2
4                PK,K,1,2
Name: Grades_Offered_All, dtype: object
PK,K,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8
```

My expected output is (in the 'max' case):

```py
(660, 1)
0          PK,K,1,2,3,4,5
1    PK,K,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8
2    PK,K,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8
3                   K,1,2
4                PK,K,1,2
Name: Grades_Offered_All, dtype: object
0    5
1    8
2    8
3    2
4    2
```

My expected output is (in the 'min' case):

```py
(660, 1)
0          PK,K,1,2,3,4,5
1    PK,K,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8
2    PK,K,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8
3                   K,1,2
4                PK,K,1,2
Name: Grades_Offered_All, dtype: object
0    PK
1    PK
2    PK
3    K
4    PK
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should create your own functions that find the min/max and use .apply to create columns with the min and max of each row. Trying find the min/max based on the individual cell placement would be messy.

Example:

```
import pandas as pd


def max_school(row):
    order = ['PK', 'K', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8']
    sort = sorted(row.dropna(), key=lambda x:order.index(x))
    return sort[-1]

def min_school(row):
    order = ['PK', 'K', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8']
    sort = sorted(row.dropna(), key=lambda x:order.index(x))
    return sort[0]

df = pd.read_csv('something.csv', dtype=str)

df['Max'] = df.apply(lambda x: max_school(x), axis=1)
df['Min'] = df.apply(lambda x: min_school(x), axis=1)

print(df)
```

This outputs:

```
     1    2    3    4    5    6    7  8  9 10 Max Min
0  NaN  NaN  NaN   PK    K    1    2  3  4  5   5  PK
1   PK    K    1    2    3    4    5  6  7  8   8  PK
2   PK    K    1    2    3    4    5  6  7  8   8  PK
3  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  K  1  2   2   K
4  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN   PK  K  1  2   2  PK
```